# How to make a complex Map Writable in java for writing it to Hadoop DFS

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a Map{String,Object}. Here the Object(value for the map) could be either a String or Map{String,String}.

So if I split up the Map it could be something like this :

Map{String,Map{string,String}} and Map{String,String}

I want to write this Map to Hadoop DFS using sequence file in a key,value pair. I want this Map to be value for by sequence file and hence needs to make it writable. I have written on class but it gives me issues if I write multiple records, then while reading it back, values from adjacent records gets mixed up.

Please suggest me some solution to this problem, or sample code to make this nested Map writable.

Comment: Can you post what code you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't owe to make your map Writable, you can just serialize it to bytes with your serialization framework of choice like java serialization or protobuf and writes bytes to your sequence file.

Comment: Here I am writing it to hadoop dfs using sequence files. So it needs the object(Map) to be Writable or else you cannot write using sequence files in Hadoop.

Comment: @Ankur - you can write what you want to sequence files, as long as you define a serialization factory that knows how to serialize and deserialize the objects. The default serialization factory is `core.org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization`, but you can configure hadoop to use something different, such as `core.org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization` which accepts any java object that implements `Serializable`. You can change the serialization factory via the `io.serializations` configuration property

Comment: @Ankur I mean you can serialize your map with whatever serialization framework you like and that put data to sequence file via BytesWritable.